# How to add scroll bar and sub-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a vertical navigation bar with icons which on hover display text along with icon with reference to [JFarrow's](https://codepen.io/JFarrow/pen/fFrpg)

```
           <li class="has-subnav">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Stars Components
                    </span>
                </a>
               <ul class="sub-menu-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Security</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
```

I would like to add sub-menus and scroll bar for sub-menus and main menu.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Rahul. Please share the CSS you have tried already.

Comment: Do you want to do it without `js`?

Comment: I was trying to do it using react but it is not working. I want to do it with or without js.

Comment: @Mike, https://codepen.io/rahul732010/pen/WNeLZxw